# Is there any performance testing of Neo4j, and pros & cons of using it in real world practice

Tags: graph, neo4j, nosql, cypher, graph-databases

**backgroud**:

- I'm a newbie for neo4j (or do not have large neo4j project experience).
- currently we start a new project about financial knowledge graph, which will be the core role for our later products.
- most of our team are financial background

**problems**:

- we tried neo4j, and found it seems good for our product scenario;
- we don't find any performance testing about neo4j and other graph database(such as hugeGraph from Baidu)
- we don't know is there any pros and cons if we choose neo4j as our graph database

**help**:

- if you've done or read some performance testing about graph database(especially about neo4j), please show us some testing report
- if you've used neo4j in your project, please share some experience about neo4j in your real world project
- if you've something you think worth sharing, we're very grade to hear that

**great thanks**

Comment: You may find it more useful to join the [neo4j-users slack](https://neo4j.com/developer/slack/) to get feedback from actual users.

Answer (score 0):

I have never done testing on Neo4j but I've used Neo4j for over a year on a social networking application. It is really fast for highly connected data but you need to be careful on how you model the graph, if you do that right it's sweet, high performance and great developer experience, the opposite is true, if you don't pay attention at how you will be querying the graph at modeling time, you better be prepared for low performance.

Thumbs up for Neo4j for being fantastically flexible and often you can fix your modeling mistakes by adding more structure to the graph.

I've enjoyed working with it so far, I've worked with other relational and non-relational databases such as MongoDB and SQL. I have to say that if your data is highly connected then Neo4j is the way to go.